# The \not operator and relation R

Tags: symbols, relation-symbols

I am using letter R for notation for my relation. I have to use the `wRw` notation. My problem is that I can't write `\not R` as I would like to. So I would like to write that, let's say a,b are not in relation with each other and type `a\not R b`.

It just doesn't look good.

Any tips?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I think you want to look at the `centernot` package: `$a\mathrel{R}b$` and `$a\centernot{R}b$`

Comment: It works for my purpose pretty well. Sorry for the duplicate if this indeed is one.

Comment: Don't worry! However remember that `a\mathrel{R}b` is the correct input for the (non negated) symbol. With `aRb` the spacing is wrong.